# why do double quotes inside double quotes work in django

Tags: django

In a html file in django why does this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "myapp/style.css"%}" />
```

work and produces the same result as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myapp/style.css'%}" />
```

Comment: Why they would not work , this is template language and only content of template tags are processed

Comment: in the first case myapp/style.css is not quoted and in the second it it is.  Aren't quotes resolved left to right? or, in template language are they resolved from the outside in?

Comment: DTL does not care about HTML nor its end product is necessary HTML, Django template engine just process its own tags as I already written

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#the-django-template-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "myapp/style.css"%}" />
```

This is a template processed by the Django template engine. The template engine does not understand HTML. It does not care about HTML tags, their attributes, or the quotes in HTML attributes. The template engine only looks for the special tags `{% %}` and `{{ }}`, and only cares about their contents. It then replaces those tags with whatever output they produce, so the output also does not contain "quotes within quotes" and HTML also isn't confused.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.
inside {% %} or {{ }} Django template engine processes the phrase. and it happens on **server side**.

then that HTML file transfer to client web browser(chrome, edge, safari, ...) and at this point HTML engine works.

so, HTML engine (of **client side**) never encounter double quote in double quote.